# ASP.NET passing data result of buttonclick to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

So i have Analysis.aspx page as part of my website, on which i have a two DropDownLists and a Button. 
After the user selects appropriate items from the DDLs and clicks on the button, he should be shown a plot driven by the javascript i use(Jchart).

I make some calculations in my buttonclick event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string idMun = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    string year = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;

    int[] fb= getStatsFB(Convert.ToInt32(idMun), Convert.ToInt32(year));
    int[] twitter= getStatsFB(Convert.ToInt32(idMun), Convert.ToInt32(year));
}
```

Now all i want to do is pass the fb and twitter integer arrays to my javascript in Analysis.aspx so that i can include these values as data inputs for this script that should show plots on my site to the user .
SO after my page loads and user select his choices and click the button, i should run this 'plot' script with this data input and show the plot on the screen..

Any ideas how to do this??
Many Thanks,
Bojan:)

Comment: Have you looked at this thread in SO? stackoverflow.com/questions/16833553/passing-c-sharp-array-to-java-script

Comment: Unfortunately , this doesn't solve my problem .

Answer (score 0):

you can write a server side variable to javascript blocks to be used on client side like this

```
var JSSIDEUSE = '<%= SERVERSIDEVARIABLE %>';
```

Now in your case since you have arrays the above method wont work as it is...instead you can convert the integer arrays to a comma separated string and dump that string in script tag

On server inside your calculation function

```
var fbString = string.Join(",", fb);
var twitterString = string.Join(",", twitter);
```

In HTML Code inside a script block use below. Note the **'** (Singlequote). It will not work without that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var fbString = '<%= fbString %>';
   var twitterString = '<%= twitterString %>';
</script>
```

Now these variables are written out in JS ready to be consumed.
You will need to convert these variables back to array inside your plot function or before passing to the function

```
var fbArray = fbString.split(",");
```

Comment: Hey Amol, if i define these two variables in my javascript , as i expected, i get the  error : "cannot resolve symbol 'fbString'/'twitterString' "... I don't think you can just use the server side variables like this on the script. Am i wrong?

Comment: actually you have to make sure that the server variables are declared before using. These variables are resolved at runtime and get replaced on the server side with their actual values due to inline tags...have a look at this link for using inline code...http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags

Comment: nice, this could be really useful! i did it in another way and will post it soon :)